# Drupal 7 save form to database

Tags: forms, drupal, drupal-7

I'm fairly new in Drupal and I wanted to make a Training Submission Form.

If I use Drupal's Contact Form module, it will only send me an email.

What if I want it to be saved in my database? Should it be saved as a content or should I provide a new specific table?

I tried to check Webform module, but it also gives me only an option to send email.

Comment: More suitable at http://drupal.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Rikesh just curious, what makes this more suitable for drupal.stackexchange.com than all the other posts tagged for drupal? I'm trying to make sense of this.

Comment: @Coder1 - If you read http://stackoverflow.com/faq , SO is for programming stuffs such as coding ,syntax etc.

Comment: My question was specifically towards this post. Why don't you reply to all the other questions tagged with Drupal as you did this one? What makes this different? Respectfully, that is what I'm asking.

Comment: @Rikesh I can guarantee this question is no more suitable for Drupal Answers than it is here. It's far too broad for any SE site

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at [Webform](http://drupal.org/project/webform) again. You should have a webform option under your content menu.

Webform stores the submissions in the database, in addition to giving you the option to mailing the result to you.